# Blender renders dull animation

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am new to Blender and was using it for creating YT Channel Intro with templates available on Velosofy (This one: https://www.velosofy.com/template/intramazing-2d-text-intro-free-professional-intro-zxbyijehap4).

The problem is after rendering it with FFmpeg (I even tried AVI JPEg) and H.264 it doesn't render it as in preview, it becomes dull and even the object have black spots on their edges.

[image: Preview window]

[image: After Rendering]

In the Render Properties>Colour Management the value for Display device is sRGB, view transform is Standard and sequences is sRGB still it's the same...
And yes it's a video and for trying rendered image...

Comment: You're probably using the [filmic] color transform, but you want the standard color transform.

Comment: Can you please tell where to change that?

Comment: And yes what about the black spots...?

Comment: Look for [colormanagement in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#settings).

Comment: In the Render Properties>Colour Management the value for Display device is sRGB, view transform is Standard and sequences is sRGB still it's the same...